# Delete single occurrence of recurring event in blackberry calendar programmatically

Tags: blackberry, java-me, calendar

I want to know how to delete a single occurrence of recurring calendar event programmatically.

Using `eventList.removeEvent(event)` deletes the whole series from the calendar.

I have also tried getting enumeration from `eventList.items(BlackberryEventList.OCCURRING, startDate, endDate, true)` and then deleting the event whose start date and end date is matched but still it deletes the whole series. According to the api this function should return me the first instance of recurring event when I specify true in the last parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing event try to update repeat rule of the particular event.

Take a look at the following methods/classes:

[setRepeat() method of Event class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/pim/Event.html#setRepeat%28javax.microedition.pim.RepeatRule%29)

[RepeatRule class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/pim/RepeatRule.html)

[addExceptDate() method of RepeatRule class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/pim/RepeatRule.html#addExceptDate%28long%29)